# How to cover anonymous function used in react router by jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, jestjs

How to test anonymous function used to supply component to the component property? If we can't test anonymous function by jest, then what should be the approach?

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={routerPath1} component={props => <MyComponent1 {...props} customProperty={BlaBlaBla} />
        <Route path={routerPath2} component={props => <MyComponent2 {...props} customProperty={BlaBlaBla} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

component={props => <MyComponent2 {...props} customProperty={BlaBlaBla} /> is not accessible by test.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `BrowserRouter` shouldn't be used in unit tests. A hierarchy of components should allow to use `MemoryRouter` instead. Then route components can be tested by changing routes.

Alternatively, anonymous function can be reached and tested separately:

```
const RouteComponent = wrapper.find(Route).at(0).props().component;
const routeComponentWrapper = shallow(<RouteComponent/>);
...
```

Testability can be improved by DRYing the code up. Since components in both routes are similar, they could be created by single higher-order component that adds `customProperty={BlaBlaBla}` prop and can be spied in tests.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!! Thanks again for other suggestions too. I started cleaning :)